# Facebook OAuth - get email address

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building a site and I would like to have FB login on it. It's almost all fine for the login part, except I can't get the email address. I'm using the PHP API. I've set the permissions on FB to ask for 'email', it said it could take several minutes, but it's been a day already, and when I try to login with my FB account on my site it still won't ask for the email permission.

Anyone could tell me please whats going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First off..  if you're using php sdk..  just entering the fact that your app wants email permission in the app setting on the facebook site doesnt do it.  Your php code has to account for the fact that you are requesting email permissions.  Without seeing your code I'm not sure how you are performing fb login..  but if you're doing it using the facebook::getLoginUrl() method, make sure you are setting your scope params to include email permissions ie:

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes, email',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page'
);
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

If you're already doing that... how about if you go into app center and un-authenticate yourself from your app  (ie by clicking on the small x top-right corner next to your app)..
Then go back to your app and refresh a few times so it recognizes that the access token has been revoked... and login again..   On the facebook prompt, does it mention that the app is asking for permission to email?

If you find that works..  then it means your issue here is that your app was using an old access token from before you started asking for email permission.  if you're still in dev mode you can just have your devs/testers do the same thing.  If not, you may need to programmatically test whether the user's active token includes the email permissions.. and if not, force a revoke of the token and direct the user back to login.

On the other hand.. if the permissions prompt doesnt mention that your app is asking for email permissions,  then it means there is something wrong with your permissions scope string or login request in which case youll need to post your code for further assessment

Answer (score 0):

The permissions you set in Facebook only apply to users who are getting to your app via the [Facebook App Center](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appcenter/). You'll need to update your login code to request the "email" permission.